# MarkLogic Data hub JOBS DB search options config

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I need to customize the search options for the JOBS DB.  There is an OOTB jobs.xml search options config file being loaded by the mlLoadModules gradle task, but I don't know where I can override it.  According to this [page](https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/refs/project-structure-4_0_x/), I should put JOBS DB artifacts in `src/main/ml-modules-jobs`.  So I tried `src/main/ml-modules-jobs/options/jobs.xml`, but that did not load. If anyone has any suggestions for how to customize JOBS DB search options, please share.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more research, I've discovered that instead of allowing ml-gradle to use the folder structure to determine which appserver to load the options for, apparently only the ../ml-modules/options location is supported and those files all get loaded for the FINAL appserver (i.e., like /Default/data-hub-FINAL/rest-api/options/).  But, in ml-gradle ver 3.12.0, there was a new task type added: `com.marklogic.gradle.task.client.CopySearchOptionsTask` that can be used to create a custom task to copy the options file from the FINAL appserver location to the JOBS appserver location in the modules db.  This works for me, though its another step to execute this task after each mlLoadModules task.  See [this doc](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/How-modules-are-loaded#copying-search-options-to-additional-app-servers) for more info.